# How do i remove style from jasper print object?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I would like to know, is it possible to remove a style from jasperPrint object.What i'm looking is, let say i have two JRStyle objects , styleForPdf and styleForExcel . By default i have set style of amount column as  **styleForPdf** . I would like to remove this style and replace it with **styleForExcel** while export this report as excel.

I tried to do this with **removeStyle** of Jasperprint, but it seems to be remove style only from a collection not removing the styles of a field.

Is it possible to do this.

Thanx